# How to covert HERE incidents RDS-TMC data to geometries (points)

Tags: here-api

I'm using the HERE traffic API such as:

http://traffic.cit.api.here.com/traffic/6.0/incidents.xml?bbox=43.8,-79.5;43.6,-79.4&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&status=active&maxresults=50

The XML returns:

```
...
<RDS-TMC>
  <ORIGIN>
    <EBU_COUNTRY_CODE>C</EBU_COUNTRY_CODE>
    <TABLE_ID>9</TABLE_ID>
    <LOCATION_ID>04184</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_DESC>DUFFERIN ST/EXIT 364</LOCATION_DESC>
    <RDS_DIRECTION>-</RDS_DIRECTION>
  </ORIGIN>
  <TO>
    <EBU_COUNTRY_CODE>C</EBU_COUNTRY_CODE>
    <TABLE_ID>9</TABLE_ID>
    <LOCATION_ID>04187</LOCATION_ID>
    <LOCATION_DESC>HWY-11A/AVENUE RD/EXIT 367</LOCATION_DESC>
    <RDS_DIRECTION>-</RDS_DIRECTION>
  </TO>
  <DIRECTION>+</DIRECTION>
  <ALERTC>
    <TRAFFIC_CODE>701</TRAFFIC_CODE>
    <QUANTIFIERS>0</QUANTIFIERS>
    <DESCRIPTION>(Q) (--//set of//sets of) roadwork</DESCRIPTION>
    <ALERTC_DURATION>L</ALERTC_DURATION>
    <ALERTC_DIRECTION>1</ALERTC_DIRECTION>
    <UPDATE_CLASS>11</UPDATE_CLASS>
    <PHRASE_CODE>E1</PHRASE_CODE>
    <EXTENT>3</EXTENT>
    <DURATION>0</DURATION>
  </ALERTC>
</RDS-TMC>
...
```

Is there any API to turn the RDS-TMC section information to geometries (points):
Maybe something like this for example:

```
<Path><Point lat,long /><Point lat,long />[snip]<Point lat,long /><Point lat,long /></Path>
```

Anything that returns the road geometry (lat, long) will do. Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the latitude and longitude elements within the geoloc/origin ? Maybe store these in a look up table? I know not all elements are always present, so you may need to use [Street Intersection Gecoding](http://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?city=Chicago&street=State%20@%20Madison&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg) in the [Geocoding API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder) as well. [Street geometry](https://route.st.nlp.nokia.com/routing/6.2/getlinkinfo.json?waypoint=52.5308,13.3846&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg) is available from the [Enterprise Routing API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-routing)

Answer (score 0):

I’m not aware of an API that does exactly what you want (then again, I’m not too familiar with HERE services, so there may be something I’ve missed).

The XML you are posting looks like a decoded TMC message, with the `<origin>` and `<to>` elements describing the start and end of the affected route. To work even over low-bandwidth connections such as RDS, TMC just transmits 16-bit location codes and relies on lookup tables in the receiver for all the rest; HERE seems to be doing some of that work for you by resolving the description for eqach location.

Three elements in each of these uniquely identify the location: `<ebu_country_code>` and `<table_id>` identify the location table, and `<location_id>` identyfies a unique location within that table. You could decode this into coordinates by obtaining the location table (rather, one location table for each area you want to cover). These will give you one point each for `<origin>` and `<to>`. For longer stretches of road, where there are additional TMC locations between these two points, you could walk through the table and obtain these as well (on highways, there is usually al location for each junction and each rest area). However, it would still not give you a complete road geometry—you would need to use map data for that.

A list of sources for TMC location datasets (not exhaustive, though) is [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TMC#Available_datasets).